# How to change Android file permissions in internal memory to be MODE_PRIVATE?

Tags: android, file-io

I have an app that tries to read a file in internal memory in it's /data/data/appname folder. However, I need to inject that file within that folder before it can read it (assuming this is a rooted device).

How do I change the permissions such that only the app can read it? I tried to programmatically create a file, and then use chmod to check the permissions, and the user/group are both app_18. How do I create a file with the same parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android when you create a file in application's internal storage `(/data/data/<package_name>)` By default it has a **MODE_PRIVATE** permission. (Its private to your application)

[**Android - InternalStorage**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)